# JAVA_HOME is incorrectly set when launching Zookeeper on Windows

Tags: windows, command-line, environment-variables, apache-zookeeper, java-home

I'm having a "JAVA_HOME is incorrectly set" error when launching Zookeeper on windows with **zkServer.cmd** while it is correctly set!
When I issue `%JAVA_HOME%` I got `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45` which is the correct directory of the java instalation.

I suspect the problem is due to the space in program files, as when I issue `%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe` (the command used in **zkEnv.cmd**) I got:

```
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

How I can fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quote the path.

"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe"

Comment: quote the path of JAVA_HOME as it has space in the path for Program Files.

Answer (score 4):

in my environment i setted to:

JAVA_HOME=C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_65

---

Note for Windows users on 64-bit systems

Progra~1 = 'Program Files'

Progra~2 = 'Program Files(x86)'

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. And i fix it.

You can change the content [%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java] to ["%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java"] in zkEnv.cmd. It needs the quota.

then run the zkServer.cmd .  it works well.

Answer (score 0):

In zkEnv.cmd file, they had changed from JAVA_HOME to JAVA only. I added JAVA in Enviorment Path and it worked, or you can change from JAVA to JAVA_HOME in zkEnv.cmd file and it will work

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem:

My issue was resolved because Windows editors cannot recognize the space between folders.

Changing from: `set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\jdk1.8.0_281`

to: `set JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\jdk1.8.0_281"`

Fixed the Issue for me

Answer (score 0):

If JAVA_HOME is not set or you don't have access to set it,

add below to the startup batch files at the top,

set JAVA_HOME=C:"location"\java\jdk1.8.0_192

Answer (score 0):

For windows 11, I've added to variables: **JAVA_HOME** and value **C:\Program Files\Java**,and then edited variable **Path**, added **%JAVA_HOME%**

Answer (score 0):

For windows server 2016 and JDK 11 running via git bash, I kept receiving:

`[0.006s][error][logging] Error opening log file '/e/apps/Apache/Kafka/kafka_2.13-3.6.0/bin/../logs/zookeeper-gc.log': No such file or directory`

`[0.006s][error][logging] Initialization of output 'file=/e/apps/Apache/Kafka/kafka_2.13-3.6.0/bin/../logs/zookeeper-gc.log' using options 'filecount=10,filesize=100M' failed.`

`Invalid -Xlog option '-Xlog:gc*:file=/e/apps/Apache/Kafka/kafka_2.13-3.6.0/bin/../logs/zookeeper-gc.log:time,tags:filecount=10,filesize=100M', see error log for details.`

`Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.`

`Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.`

I had seen it required a minimum Java version of 8+ and that it was moaning about some logging, I had seen in the  kafka-run.sh that it was doing something funky based on the java version with the log files so I set it instead to JDK 8 and everything started properly (zookeeper wise).  I then tried to start kafka and it started fine.

Note: my java path and home were messed up/not present so in
`kafka-run-class.sh` I did add at the top:

`JAVA_HOME=/C/apps/jdk1.8.0_241`

`JAVA=/C/apps/jdk1.8.0_241/bin/java`